# Creating a C# Application under Ubuntu

Tags: c#

I wanted to ask, is it possible to develop c# applications with windows forms under ubuntu with the official .NET core. Am asking because at school we learn c#, but how do I do my homeworks? I know that a windows dualboot or virtualbox could solve the problem, but wanna know if there is a native way? Using Mono or Wine are not native for example, as there is no full support, while .Net core is open source but without windows forms, meaning it is useless for my school

Comment: See [Importing and developing WinForms applications on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8627018) and http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/

Comment: Did you try wine?

Comment: I'm confused, it looks like you already answered your own question in the last sentence.